# Migrating InfoPath from 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint, migration, infopath, infopath2010

How can I migrate my existing InfoPath form 2010 to InfoPath 2013? Will opening the form in IP 2013 and publish work?

Answer (score 0):

Opening the form in 2013 will work as it is backwards compatible with older versions. If you want to, you could always edit the form and change the compatability to the newest form type.